# gdebi doesn't finish installing rstudio service

Tags: services, r, gdebi

Cross posted from https://community.rstudio.com/t/ubuntu-rstudio-server-upgrade-service-not-found/27621

I had a working v1.1.463 installation of the Rstudio server on one of my Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS comupters, but I made a  mess of trying to upgrade to v1.2.1335-1 Preview.  I'm in a state now where I don't get any errors from installing it with

> sudo gdebi rstudio-1.2.1335-amd64.deb

but the `service` command implies that the service has not been installed.  See below.

***Does gdebi have a verbose mode, or is there some way for me to extract the installation commands from the .deb file?***

Note, I had reinstalled rJava as root, after the error about that at 12:44:24.  `$JAVA_HOME` is not set.

```
$ sudo service rstudio-server status
● rstudio-server.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Apr 03 12:44:24 ip-172-31-90-126 systemd[1]: Stopping RStudio Server...
Apr 03 12:44:24 ip-172-31-90-126 systemd[1]: Stopped RStudio Server.
Apr 03 12:44:24 ip-172-31-90-126 rsession-rstudio[1524]: ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=Error in .requirePackage(package) : |||  unable to find required package ‘rJava’|||]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::
Apr 03 12:44:24 ip-172-31-90-126 rsession-trustedcolleague[1777]: ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::r::exec::executeSafely(rstudio_boost::function<void()>) /home/ubuntu/rstud
Apr 03 12:44:43 ip-172-31-90-126 systemd[1]: Stopped RStudio Server.

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.16.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

$ R

R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) -- "Great Truth"

> library("rJava")
>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ugh.  I had tried to "upgrade" from the `rstudio-server-1.1.463-amd64.deb` **server** to the `rstudio-1.2.1335-amd64.deb` **desktop application**.  I have the 1.2 server running now.

Comment: Makes sense - `gdebi` can only be expected to resolve dependencies that are available from your configured repositories (although it might be helpful if it provided more diagnostic output to that effect)